# PHP not inserting data into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to insert data into phpmyadmin database.
It is not giving any error but when i look into php my admin no data is inserted:

Here Is the Code:

```
    <?php //get the data and assign to variables
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $username = $_POST["Username"];
        $email = $_POST["Email"];
        $password = $_POST["Password"];

        $gender = $_POST["Gender"];

        $bestKnowLanguage = $_POST["Languages"];

        $DOB = $_POST["DOB"];
        $DOB_Splitted = preg_split("/-/", $DOB);

        $DOB_Year = $DOB_Splitted[0];
        $DOB_Month = $DOB_Splitted[1];
        $DOB_Date = $DOB_Splitted[2];

        $DOB_Formatted = date('d-m-y',strtotime($_POST['DOB']));

        echo "$username<br>";
        echo "$email<br>";
        echo "$password<br>";
        echo "$gender<br>";
        echo "Best Known Language ".$bestKnowLanguage.'<br>';
        echo "$DOB<br>";

            if (!empty($_POST['languages'])) {
               foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $value) {
               echo $value.' ';
               }
             }
       }
    ?>
```

the database connection :

```
 <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "coders");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO coder_system(email,username,password,gender,DOB,known_language,best_known_language) VALUES ('$email','$username','$password','$gender','$DOB_Formatted','$bestKnowLanguage','$bestKnowLanguage')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            echo "Successfull";
        }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure all the datapoints are being posted? Could you share your HTML too>

Comment: I am sure that values are not null because when i am printing them i get the entered value...

Comment: "password" is a reserved word in SQL. I read somewhere that you should use backticks for column names to prevent issues (e.g., `\`password\``)

Comment: Not related to your question, but yet important: read about XSS and SQL injection and how to prevent it on PHP. The shared code is vulnerable to those types of attacks and shouldn't be used on a public-facing environment.

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be that it is baulking on your DOB field, mysql dates should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD you are using d-m-y

Did you try changing `$DOB_Formatted = date('d-m-y',strtotime($_POST['DOB']));` to `$DOB_Formatted = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['DOB']));` as suggested ?